# xcode 4.5.2 how to create view based application

Tags: xcode, xcode4.5

i want to build view based application with xcode 4.5.2 but when i create new project all i see is on the photo below , there is no type called "view based application" , is the "Single View Application" or what?[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, use the "Single View Application".

BTW - you could have just tried it to see what you get. It's OK to experiment. Try each one to see what they do. Build and run each in the simulator. This is a great way to learn. You'll have plenty of examples.

Don't be afraid to create lots of simple projects to try things out.

Comment: you right man thank you alot , i was asking because i am new to xcode :)